# Android EditText: When ist the hovering paste button shown

Tags: android, android-edittext

i am working with an existing application, which used EditText controls. One thing, which confuses me is, that sometime (when the cursor is moved by touch), a hovering paste button is displayed (often after copying texts), but more often, when the cursor is moved by touch, only the grip arrow (to drag the text) is shown alone.
I didn't find out, what is the reason or which triggers the paste button to display.
One more question: is there any possibility to prevent the cursor drag symbol?

Comment: Paste trigged on `LongClick` if you want to disable it you can add `android:longClickable="false"` in xml .

Comment: thank you. do you also know, if this is it possible to deactivate that from program code?

Comment: You can also call `view.setLongClickable(false)`. It will does same .

Comment: ehm, it appears not on long click, but  if i simply click at another location (when cursor position changes). Anyway I try it out. The paste button is still appearing. Anyway. i need long click for my edittext context menu.

Comment: I just discovered. The paste button appears, if I copied just before something from selected text to clipboard. It is  active until 15 seconds after the last copy happened. It looks, like a timer is running in the background. Vety strange, i could not find any information about that in google or here in stackoverflow. Android people could provide clearer information about that.

Comment: I just confirmed this behaviour also in other apps, where apparantly EditText or TextView control/class is used. In the first 15 seconds after copying a text/selection, a hovering paste button apoears, if selection is changed. After that time, no paste button is displayed anymore.

Comment: If you figure out the concept . Please answer your own question with proper details .

Answer (score 0):

After long time I stumbled upon that again. I saw the answer of that in the file:
.../sdk/sources/android-21/android/widget/Editor.java

Part of code at InsertationHandleView:

```
    private class InsertionHandleView extends HandleView {
    private static final int DELAY_BEFORE_HANDLE_FADES_OUT = 4000;
    private static final int RECENT_CUT_COPY_DURATION = 15 * 1000; // seconds

    // Used to detect taps on the insertion handle, which will affect the ActionPopupWindow
    private float mDownPositionX, mDownPositionY;
    private Runnable mHider;

    public InsertionHandleView(Drawable drawable) {
        super(drawable, drawable);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();

        final long durationSinceCutOrCopy =
                SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - TextView.LAST_CUT_OR_COPY_TIME;
        if (durationSinceCutOrCopy < RECENT_CUT_COPY_DURATION) {
            showActionPopupWindow(0);
        }
```